# Refresh page on popup close?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

So I've used javascript to open a popup window in asp.net with c# codebehind, and I need a buttonclick event on the popup to both close the popup and refresh the parent page. Is there a method for this?

Comment: You can access `window.opener` from within the popup so `window.opener.location.reload` could do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the location/refresh the parent window you can use the opener property.

This one will change the href of the parent from the pop-up.

```
window.opener.location.href = the_url;
```

The `reload` method will work too, 
This does a hard reload (returns forms to default values)
The optional boolean conditional argument will if true make a new request of the server, if false it will attempt to pull the page from the cache.

```
window.opener.location.reload(true);
```

If you want to preserve form data (soft reload), use the history method.

```
window.opener.history.go(0);
```

'0' causes the page to reload, a negative value represents how many steps backward you'd like to go.

Answer (score 0):

Also try this

```
window.location.href=window.location.href
```